# How to use different background color for every listview item

Tags: java, android, listview

Hello friends I am using a custom listview and this color picker library '    implementation 'petrov.kristiyan:colorpicker-library:1.1.5' here is link   library link https://github.com/kristiyanP/colorpicker my problem is that when any user click on any particular item in the listview the color dialog is popped up so user can pick color in this dialog box and change background color of a particular item which successfully I done. But my problem is that how I can save this state for later used here is my picture you get idea what actually i want?

here my picture

[here is picture of highlight two  item with different color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12Hzc.png)

how can save the state ?

my custom adopter code

package bible.swordof.God;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.opengl.Visibility;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.TextDrawable;
import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.util.ColorGenerator;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty;
import petrov.kristiyan.colorpicker.ColorPicker;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;
import static android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_NONE;
import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.V;
import static android.support.constraint.Constraints.TAG;
import static android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext;
import static android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startActivity;

public class FullverseAdopter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private ALLVERSE activity;

    private List<String> versenumber;
    private List<String>verseid;
    private List<String> verselist;
    private List<String> refernce;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private  int selectcolor;
    ArrayList<String>colors;



    public FullverseAdopter(ALLVERSE context, int resource, List<String> versenumber, List<String> verselist, List<String> refernce, List<String>verseid) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.activity = context;
        this.versenumber = versenumber;
        this.verselist = verselist;
        this.refernce = refernce;
        this.verseid=verseid;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return versenumber.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return versenumber.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // If holder not exist then locate all view from UI file.
        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate UI from XML file
             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.versedisplayrow, parent, false);
            // get all UI view
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            // set tag for holder
           holder.versenumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.versenumber);
            holder.verselist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.verse);
            holder.addfavoruite=(ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.adbookmark);




            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // if holder created, get tag from view
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.versenumber.setText(versenumber.get(position));

        holder.verselist.setText(verselist.get(position));

        //check if id is exits in db
        if(CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot("highlight","verseid",verseid.get(position)))
        {
            if(verseid.get(position).equals(verseid.get(position))){







            }




        }
else {

        }

holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(selectcolor);

        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
        mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        long delete= mDb.delete("highlight","verseid=?",new String[]{verseid.get(position)});

        Toast.makeText(activity, "Remove highlight", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});


//here color picker dialog popup for chosing color

holder.linearLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {


    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
        mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("verseid",verseid.get(position));
        long check=mDb.insert("highlight",null,contentValues);



        //Toasty.success(activity, "PICK COLOR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
        Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator)activity.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibe.vibrate(100);


        //id get

        Toast.makeText(activity, ""+verseid.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        //postion
        //Toast.makeText(activity, ""+getItemId(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(activity);
       colors=new ArrayList<>();
        colors.add("#e0e0eb");
        colors.add("#ccffff");
        colors.add("#ffe6ff");
        colors.add("#ffffcc");
        colors.add("#ccffcc");
        colors.add("#e6f2ff");

        colorPicker.setColors(colors).setColumns(4).setTitle("HIGHLIGHT VERSE").setRoundColorButton(true).setOnChooseColorListener(new ColorPicker.OnChooseColorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChooseColor(int position, int color) {



                holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }
        }).show();






        return false;
    }
});
        /*holder.verselist.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                holder.verselist.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e0e0eb"));
                return false;
            }
        });*/




        //share verse
        holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toasty.info(activity, "Sharing a verse.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, refernce.get(position) + ":" + versenumber.get(position) + '\n'   + verselist.get(position));
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                activity.startActivity(sendIntent);

            }
        });

//add in favourite
      holder.addfavoruite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked){
                    mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
                    mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
                  contentValues.put("id",verseid.get(position));
                  contentValues.put("bookname",refernce.get(position));
                   contentValues.put("versenumber",versenumber.get(position));
                   contentValues.put("verse",verselist.get(position));
                   long check=mDb.insert("favourite",null,contentValues);


                   Log.d("MY_TAG","DB IS NOW "+check);
                   Toasty.success(activity, "Added in favouite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();


                }else {


                    mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
                    mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    long delete= mDb.delete("favourite","id=?",new String[]{verseid.get(position)});
                   Toasty.error(activity, "Remove in favouite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                }


            }
        });

       /* textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(activity, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {

                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(activity, "YOUR DEVICE NOT SUPPORTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
*/



        //My toggle button








       /* holder.speakverse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(activity, "I AM CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA) {

                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Language not supported or Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {


                    textToSpeech.speak(verselist.get(position), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                }
            }
        });*/




        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView versenumber;
        private TextView verselist;

        private ImageView share;
        private  ToggleButton addfavoruite;
        private ImageView speakverse;
        private LinearLayout linearLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            versenumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.versenumber);
            verselist = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.verse);
           share = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.share);
            /*speakverse = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.speakverse);*/
        addfavoruite=(ToggleButton)v.findViewById(R.id.adbookmark);
        linearLayout=(LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.layout);



        }


    }
    public boolean CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(String TableName,  String dbfield, String fieldValue) {

        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
        mDb = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String Query = "Select * from " + TableName + " where " + dbfield + " = " + fieldValue;
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
            cursor.close();

           // Toast.makeText(activity, "false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }else {

              // Toast.makeText(activity, "TRUE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        cursor.close();


        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have all your item properties in one object and add the background color to it.

When a color is picked just save it to your verse object and when view is created set it.
Also add the background to your `ViewHolder`.

```
public class Verse {
    private String versenumber;
    private String verseid;
    private String verselist;
    private String refernce;
    private int backgroundColor

    // Getters and setters
}

public class FullverseAdopter extends ArrayAdapter<Verse> {
    private ALLVERSE activity;

    private List<Verse> verse;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private  int selectcolor;
    ArrayList<String>colors;


    public FullverseAdopter(ALLVERSE context, int resource, List<Verse> verse) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.activity = context;
        this.verse = verse;
    }

    // The rest of your code
}
```